# Python multithreading increased 3x execute time rather than reducing it

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, optimization, python-multithreading

there is a [challenge](https://training.cyberchallenge.it/#/task/maxofmin/statement) that I want to optimize, so I started with this basic code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def solve(N, V):
  
  solution = []

  solution.append(max(set(V)))

  ln = len(V)
  
  for length in range(2, N+1):

    ptrs = [ n for n in range(length) ]

    maxofmin = min(set([ V[n] for n in ptrs ]))

    while ptrs[-1] < ln-1:

      try:

          ptrs[:] = [ n+1 for n in ptrs ]

          tmp = min(set([ V[n] for n in ptrs ]))

          maxofmin = tmp if tmp > maxofmin else maxofmin

      except:
        break

    solution.append(maxofmin)
  
  return solution

if __name__ == "__main__":
  N = int(input().strip())
  V = list(map(int, input().strip().split(" ")))
```

I thought that multithreading would have been a good choice since it would have allowed me to compute simultaneously 3 minimums of length L rather than 1 by 1 waiting for the other to be computed, so here's how I implemented it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import threading, queue

q1 = queue.Queue()
q2 = queue.Queue()

mins_3 = set() 

def retrieveMin1():
    
    mins_3.add(min(set(q1.get())))
    q1.task_done()

def retrieveMin2():
    a = q2.get()
    mins_3.add(min(set(a)))
    q2.task_done()
            

def solve(N, V):
    global mins_3
    solution = [0] * N 
    V_set = set(V)

    abs_min = min(V_set)
    abs_max = max(V_set)

    solution[0] = abs_max
    solution[-1] = abs_min

    for l in range(2, N): 

        mins = set()

        for i in range(0, N-l+1, 3): 

            t1 = threading.Thread(target=retrieveMin1, daemon=True).start()
            t2 = threading.Thread(target=retrieveMin2, daemon=True).start()

            tmp1 = V[i:i+l]
            if len(tmp1) == l:
                q1.put(tmp1) 


            tmp2 = V[i+1:1+i+l]
            if len(tmp2) == l:
                q2.put(tmp2) 
            
                
            tmp = V[i+2:i+2+l]
            if len(tmp) == l:
                mins_3.add(min(set(tmp))) 

            q1.join()
            q2.join()

            mins.add(max(mins_3)) 

            mins_3 = set()

        solution[l-1] = max(mins)
  
    return solution

if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = int(input().strip())
    V = list(map(int, input().strip().split(" ")))
    print(" ".join(map(str, solve(N, V))))
```

Unfortunately, execution time increased from 30s to 1min30s (I expected it to be around 10s..); can someone explain me why does this happen?

There's also another issue that happened and cannot explain to myself how does it happen: as you can see `retrieveMin1()` and `retrieveMin2()` do the same thing but they are written in two different ways; the reason behind this choice is that while debugging my code I noticed that in two or three calls (with an input of around 100 numbers bigger than 10000 (or even 100000) ) the second function didn't add the minimum to the set (yes, it was different from all the other elements of the set) resulting in a wrong output, even thought `retrieveMin2()` got fully executed; for debug reasons I stored the element of the queue rather than elaborating it directly and noticed that with this simple change there were no bugs anymore. Can someone explain me why does this happen?

P.S. I know that there are other methods to optimize this challenge, but now my curiosity is focused on why multithreading made things worse

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Followed @Carcigenicate advice on multiprocessing but... on a testcase of 1000 numbers it required 1min45s, which is 15 seconds more than the multithreading. Am I doing something wrong?

```
        #!/usr/bin/python3

import  multiprocessing


def retrieveMin(_list):

    return min(set(_list))
            

def solve(N, V):

    solution = [0] * N 
    V_set = set(V)

    abs_min = min(V_set)
    abs_max = max(V_set)

    solution[0] = abs_max
    solution[-1] = abs_min

    with multiprocessing.Pool(3) as pool:

        for l in range(2, N): 

            mins = set()

            for i in range(0, N-l+1, 3): 

                    data = [  V[i+n:i+n+l]  for n in range(3) if len(V[i+n:i+n+l] ) == l]
                    mins.add(max(pool.map(retrieveMin,  data)))

            solution[l-1] = max(mins)
      
    return solution

if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = int(input().strip())
    V = list(map(int, input().strip().split(" ")))
    print(" ".join(map(str, solve(N, V))))
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why single thread single process is way more efficient than a mt/mp?

Comment: You can't use multithreading for work that's CPU-bound in CPython due to the GIL. Try again with `multiprocessing`'s `Process` instead. You'll need to change up some stuff though to allow for inter-process communication, since you won't be able to just mutate global objects like you are here.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Oh, I'm reading that basically CPython executes only one thread at time, that's really disappointing. Is there a way to bypass it/change the option or is multiprocessing the only way to do parallel computations? (and with multiprocessing is there any limit of processes? Is it still a good choice?)

Comment: I think there's a macro that disables the GIL if you dip into C, but for straight Python, you're stuck with multiprocessing afaik. You could switch to a different interpreter too.

Comment: And I haven't used multiprocessing much. Lately, any time I've needed to do multiple things at once, it was carrying out I/O, so multithreading worked fine. For limits though, obviously you're limited by the cores on your system, what else is running at the time, and any OS specific limitations on numbers of running processes. Beyond that though, you should be able to spawn as many processes as you like.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I tried multiprocess and edited the question, things got way worse

Comment: Creating the pool inside of a 2D loop isn't a good idea. The main reason to use a pool is to reuse processes so they don't need to be recreated everytime they're needed. Processes are expensive to create/destroy, so creating/destroying three processes per iteration will be slow. The pool should probably remain intact for the entirety of `solve`

Comment: You might want to also play around with `map`s `chunksize` argument. The chunk size will greatly affect performance as well.

Comment: @Carcigenicate my idea was to calculate in parallel around 3/6 minimums, so I use multiprocess to run 3/6 processes and I think that it should improve the single-process algorithm since multiprocessing would let me calculate 6 results at the same time rather than 1 by 1; I'm trying to play around with the chunk size but it seems like it's only getting worse and I cant' understand why